# Is writing DHCP client on Windows Phone 8 even possible?

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, dhcp

Since I haven't installed windows 8 on PC yet, I'm not able to compile my program for phone and test whether or not will it works.

The question is: can I use DHCP ports (67 and 68), create there sockets and send/receive data in my app?

Reference of Socket API doesn't mention anything, however those ports can be locked by system DHCP client.

Answer (score 0):

Since DHCP is a simple UDP protocoll it should be possible. You just need to check if it is possible on wp8 to open the ports in that low range. In linux that requires root permission,  but luckily we use Windows.